Noise texture follows mesh topology
I'd like to create a texture that follows the topology of a mesh. So say I want a noise texture distorted to the thickness of my plane. I figure this is a UV thing, so I've tried messing with the UV layout to expand the edges, thereby scaling down the noise texture. But this doesn't work - either with a blank UV going into a procedural texture or an image texture.

Desired layout is below.


When subdividing the mesh, I get these strange lines.


Is your node setup definitely set to use UV's? Can we get a screenshot of how its set up?

Redo your mesh with only triangles or subdivide your object. This a limitation inate to quad modeling.

Subdivided quads worked better for me here. I wonder if there is a better way with gradients plugged into the vector input.

